# Computing permutation correlation: how to get averaged r value

Tags: r, permutation, correlation

i am trying to calculate a permutation correlation.
I am using this function

mz=perm.cor.test(bias1mz, bias2mz, "two.sided", "spearman")
dz=perm.cor.test(bias1dz, bias2dz, "two.sided", "spearman")

In particular I am correlating scores from twin 1 and twin 2 from both dizygotic and monozygotic twins.

Then I would like to compare these correlations, but with the permutation I only get a p value as a results.

Instead I would like to have a correlation coefficient, which should be, ideally, the mean of all the coefficient obtained in every single permutation.

Thank you all in advance for your help and let me know if I need to clarify something

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your data looks like and what the desired output is? I am unclear if this is a stats or programming question.

Comment: In my perspective is a programming question. my data look like this twin1= 1 0 3 4 5 6 7  twin2= 4 5 2 4 1 4 5. Imagine they are math test scores. Instead of doing normal correlation I would like to combine the order of the scores in order to have a N of correlations, then I want to compute the mean between them. the program I found which do that only provide with a p value, but i would like to have a correlation coefficient

Comment: Again, can you provide an example of what the output looks? Your question is vague, confusing, and doesn’t follow community standards at all.